# Target multiple elements from the style of element

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say i have multiple `div`s with the same class like

```html
<div class="myDiv">1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="display:none">3</div>
<div class="myDiv">4</div>
```

And here i want to target the div that has `display:none` which is the third div `<div class="x" style="display:none">3</div>`

**I tried using this**

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
const element = elements.find(element => element.style.display == "none");
console.log(element)
```

but i got an error saying

> elements.find is not a function

i tried to `console.log` the style of the elements to check the styles

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
elements.forEach(element => console.log(element.style.display));
```

and it outputs this which is correct

```js
""
""
"none"
""
```

But why doesn't the code that i tried work and why is `elements.find not a function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but i got an error saying
>
> > elements.find is not a function

That's because the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` isn't an array, it's a [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist). You could create an array from it before doing the `find`:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
const element = [...elements].find(element => element.style.display == "none");
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^−−−−−−−−^
console.log(element);
```

That works because `NodeList` instances are iterable, so you can use spread notation to expand them into an array literal. (Other options are `Array.from(elements)`, `Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)`, or just using a `for` loop.)

You can also narrow your selector from `.myDiv` to `.myDiv[style]` so it only matches `.myDiv` elements that have a `style` attribute.

Ideally, though, if you can change things so that you don't have that inline style in the first place, I'd do that. For instance, if you use a class to hide the element:

```
<div class="myDiv">1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div class="myDiv hidden">3</div>
<div class="myDiv">4</div>
```

where `hidden` is defined as :

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

then you can ask the browser for the specific element you're interested in:

```
const element = document.querySelector(".myDiv.hidden");
```

Comment: oh wow i didnt even know `const element = document.querySelector(".myDiv.hidden");` is possible. Great answer. Thank you so much

Comment: @Sammieboy - Glad that helped! Note that it's only possible if you change the HTML and add the CSS shown... :-)

Comment: yep, thanks i have accepted your answer too

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `Array.from`

like so :

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
const element = Array.from(elements).find(element => element.style.display == "none");
console.log(element)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that it's will diplay none the div number 3, any way you can use id as well to display none

```
  <div class="myDiv">1</div>
    <div class="myDiv">2</div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="display:none">3</div>
    <div class="myDiv">4</div>
```

*************JS****************

```
let myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
myDiv[2].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: this is not what he wanted, try reading the question again